# Angular: Create ng-class based on variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an ng-class that sets the tab class to "active" based on the current day of the week utilizing JavaScripts getDay() which applies numbers 0-6 to each day of the week. So if it's Monday, check the currentDay if it is equal to 1 apply class, if it's Tuesday's tab check the currentDay, if it is equal to 2 apply the class to tuesday, etc. e.g:

**Javascript** (I tried putting this into a $scope object in my controller but that didn't seem to work either):

```
var d = new Date();
var currentDay = d.getDay();
```

**View**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li ng-class="{'active' : currentDay == 4}">
   <a href="schedule/#thursday" data-toggle="tab">
     <h2>Day 1 | Thursday</h2>
   </a>
 </li>
 <li>
   ...
 </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried multiple different ways to get this to work. If I check currentDay == 4 in the console (since today is Thursday) it comes back as 'true'. So the class should be applied. I also tried without the ' ' around active, and putting the condition in [ ]. Nothing seems to work.. Appreciate any input, thank you!

Comment: Show what did you add on controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out!

So in the controller I added the last line below

```
var d = new Date();
var currentDay = d.getDay();
$scope.activeDay = currentDay;
```

and updated the view to read:

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : activeDay == 4}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code above works for me. Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3252/

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentDay = 4;
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{'active' : currentDay == 4}">
            <a href="schedule/#thursday" data-toggle="tab">
                <h2>Day 1 | Thursday</h2>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I had to guess, you are not applying the value to the `$scope` correctly

Comment: Thanks @Matt Way for the reply! The thing is I didn't want to set a hard value in the controller for currentDay. I wanted it to check the actual day. JavaScript's getDay() returns numbers 0-6, with 0 being Sunday - 6 being Saturday. I was able to get it to work dynamically by checking the current day, will update with answer!

Comment: @satully89: I figured that showing it as a hardcoded value would make it easier to understand, and changing it trivial. Glad you found your answer.